# Mac sharing - I am sharing folders between two macs, but not seeing any files in them

Tags: sharing

I have two Macs set up on the same WiFi network and I have connected them together so that I can access the Documents folder of Mac A from Mac B, but it shows no files in the Documents folder. It is ticked as a shared folder. I have no idea how to search for an answer to this as it all seems to be set up properly.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What version on MacOS on each Mac? Can you show us a screenshot of System Preferences > Sharing, showing the Users and Permissions for the folders? My first thought is that you have set up a "Drop box", in which files can be written, but not read.

Comment: Who has permissions on the share(s)?

Comment: Try to use another folder other than the Documents folder.

Comment: If that's in Big Sur, try with full disk access for "smbd" (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access.  smbd can be found in /usr/sbin/smbd)

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'user' accessing the shared folder the same user as the one who owns it?
If it is another user, then it is simpler to share a different folder, one outside the individual User area. The alternative is to add ACLs to the folder, permitting specific access to that other user.

I haven't tested this on Big Sur [which may try to prevent you from even doing this] but on an older OS you'd do it like this…

Select the folder.
Get Info.
Click the lock & authorise.
Click the + icon.
Add another user [this user must already have an account on this Mac] or a group the user is a member of.
Change their permissions to Read & Write.

You end up with this…

[image]

You may still have to click the gear icon & 'apply to enclosed items'.

Overall, it is simpler to use the specific Shared area inside the main Users folder, as you don't have to get cavalier with permissions.